# How to extract human height (US) from string

Tags: python, regex, string, text

If I have a string that contains a human height in the US form (feet, inches)
e.g. `I've been 5'10" since I was 18`
how can I use regex to extract the 5'10" as a tuple?
e.g. `(5, 10)`

So far I tried:

```
s = "I've been 5'10\" since I was 18"
re.findall(r'\d\'\d+\"', s)
```

Hoping to grab the first digit, which should be a single digit `\d` and then the next two digits with `\d+`, but this doesn't work very cleanly, returning `['5\'10"']` and requiring more splitting etc. Ideally there is a way to do this all with regex.

Comment: What have you tried and what precisely is the problem with it? Start with e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761.

Comment: pattern : `(\d)'(\d+)` will give you 2 groups

Comment: https://regex101.com/ helps me often

Comment: I appreciate the reference to a general guide but I don't see how that helps me answer a very specific question without investing a substantial amount of time.

Comment: Such an investment in time will pay off in the future though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
a='''I've been 5'10" since I was 18''' #triple quotes to account for " after 10
p=re.compile(r"[0-9]+'[0-9]{2}\"")
print(re.findall(p,a)[0])
```

And Voila !

Comment: Edited it to fit any possible height now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> r = re.compile('(\\d+)\'(\\d+)"')
>>> r.findall('''I've been 5'10" since I was 18''')
[('5', '10')]
```

Comment: `\\d+` -> `\d+`.